# Is it possible to only log the query and parameters, omit the result from the query in hibernate log4j

Tags: hibernate, logging, log4j, log4j2

`[DEBUG] 2023-11-24 18:58:06.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] SQL - select distinct employee0_.ID as col_0_0_ from EMPLOYEE  where employee0_.ID=?  [TRACE] 2023-11-24 18:58:06.198 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [12615] [TRACE] 2023-11-24 18:58:06.225 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] BasicExtractor - extracted value ([col_0_0_] : [BIGINT]) - [12615]`

BasicBinder maps the parameter in the query. Is there any way to omit the BasicExtractor which shows the results.

Need to only show the query and paramter, no results needed